# MySQL SELECT WHERE id IN function()

Tags: mysql, function

I have a function that returns **VARCHAR**.

It will be always empty string "" OR single ID "1" OR IDs "1,2,3,4,5".

Then I have this query:

```
SELECT id, title FROM category WHERE id IN getIds(1);
```

But it returns only first item because it is as a string, eg. 1, instead if 1,2,3.

Is there a way to tell MySQL it should use it not as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL does not support table-valued functions. You have 2 choices:

1) Use FIND_IN_SET https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set AND http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php "This function returns the location of a string given in the first argument of the function, in a comma-separated list in a string given in the second argument. The first element of the list is 1. A 0 is returned if the string is not found in the set. It returns NULL if either argument is NULL."

```
SELECT id, title FROM category WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, getIds(1)) > 0
```

2) Populate a temp table and use it with the `IN` operator

```
SELECT id, title FROM category WHERE id IN (SELECT Id FROM myTempTable)
```

Approach #1 seems more appropriate for this case.

Comment: The number is just ID of primary category.

Comment: You can also try to use find in set (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but I recommend the above approach. Typically you want to minimize your string manipulations in SQL and just use table comparisons. Makes it more maintainable and readable. Avoid dynamic SQL when possible.

Comment: How can I return a table? Can you send me a link for any example please?

Comment: MySQL does not support table-valued functions. I was thinking of SQL Server. I edited my answer, let me know if that works for you. I think you should go with the first approach since your function already returns a comma separated list.

Comment: Perfect. I used the first solution and it works. Thank you.